# Do I need a transit Visa from Macau to Addis Ababa?

Tags: transit-visas, south-korea, ugandan-citizens

I am Uganda by nationality. I traveled from Addis Ababa  aboard ET672 on 21july through Seoul  Incheon International to Macau aboard  Jejuair 7C2003 at 22:40. I was supposed to go home yesterday from Macau aboard Jejuair 7C through Seoul Incheon International and connect to  Ethiopian Airlines ET 673 on 31st July 01:05 but I was denied on grounds that I needed a visa.So could please help me to go back to my country? Do I need a transit Visa back home the way I came? Please help me.

Comment: According to Timatic you would qualify for Transit Without Visa if you could remain in the transit area at Incheon. If you needed to collect and recheck your bags, or transfer between terminals you would have needed a visa. From what I can see, Ethiopian and JejuAir both operate from Terminal 1. Did they tell you why they thought you needed a visa?

Comment: Yes the jejuair told me that Ethiopian Airlines doesn't have a transfer desk within meaning that I had to go through the immigration

Comment: If you need to pass through immigration you will need a visa. It seems strange to me that Ethiopian don't operate a transfer desk in the transit area, or arrange for some other airline to handle their transit passengers. Check with Ethiopian what arrangements they have at Incheon, if any. You might be stuck until you can get a visa.

Comment: You could just check in online for the ET flight, making a transfer desk unnecessary, though again this depends on not having any hold luggage. The Jejuair agent might not have known that, and it might not have made a difference anyway.

Comment: How did this work on the Ethiopia-Macau part of your journey?

Comment: @JJJ It must be that JejuAir has a transfer desk at Incheon taking care of connecting passengers, but it's not the case the other way around?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.